# Position DIV elements in circle

Tags: javascript, positioning, trigonometry

I need to position these 5 elements in circle. And my trigonometry knowledge is too poor to come up with a solution.

http://jsbin.com/acOSeTE/1/edit

Whoever helps please give some explanation on the math formula or forward me to a link with info about it.

I do not need a jQuery solution, since I want to learn what is behind the frameworks.

Thanks.

Comment: Always include the relevant code *in the question itself*, don't just link (not even to jsbin). A live link like that is a nice *addition*.

Comment: How do you propose to position anything without CSS?

Comment: Well it is still css but only true JavaScript as you can see I have given div.style.position, etc. I need it to be made with JavaScript.

Comment: Why is the -1? Please help me understand the logic?

Comment: Without going into specifics, you basically use 360 as your circle degrees, then divide that by the number of elements you have to position (5 in this case), and that forms the basis of your loop increment. Then you get the sin(degrees) and the cos(degrees), one you use for the y distance, and then other for the x distance, multiply the value by the radius you require and you have your positions. I can't remember if javascript Math.cos and Math.sin use radians or degrees, if it doesn't work out you might have to convert your degrees to radians (google that if you don't know how).

Comment: I imagine the -1 is because you didn't include your code here, and indicating you don't want a CSS solution makes it unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb: Radians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll almost certainly need CSS to position the divs with that kind of precision.

The general formula you're looking for is that for any given radian position on the circle (there are 2π radians in a circle), the `x` and `y` are:

```
x = originX + (Math.cos(radians) * radius);
y = originY + (Math.sin(radians) * radius);
```

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/eJUxega/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/eJUxega/1/edit)

CSS (you could use inline styles, I suppose):

```
#target {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Start/Stop">
<div id="target"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var radians, maxRadians, target, radius, originX, originY, inc, timer;

  radius = 50;
  originX = 100;
  originY = 100;

  radians = 0;
  maxRadians = 2 * Math.PI;
  inc = 10 / 360;
  target = document.getElementById("target");
  positionTarget();

  function positionTarget() {
    var x, y;

    x = originX + (Math.cos(radians) * radius);
    y = originY + (Math.sin(radians) * radius);
    console.log(x + "," + y);
    target.style.left = x + "px";
    target.style.top =  y + "px";
    radians += inc;
    if (radians > maxRadians) {
      radians -= maxRadians;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(positionTarget, 30);
  }

  document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = 0;
    }
    else {
      timer = setTimeout(positionTarget, 30);
    }
  };
})();
```